# Covert general text to number when prefixed with a ~

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a column in excel which is formatted a general and it contains numbers, some of which are prefixed with a ~. I know that this character is representing leading zeroes, but in some cases it is one, or it can be two, three or more leading zeroes.

Is there a way to convert this to a number and preserve the correct number of leading zeroes? I need this to lookup on another list and match them, and the format must be identical.

Comment: Is there a set total number of digits?

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be a way to determine how many leading zeros are required.  If you want to replace the *tilda* with a single leading *0*, then use the Replace Dialog to replace two tildas with single-quote 0:

[image]

*(use as many zeros as are required.)*